# In Gradle, is there a supported way for a static method to get a project instance?

Tags: gradle, static, project

My build has some static utility methods, and currently they have a project parameter so they can access anything, including the root project. But is there a way to omit that parameter skip, and just use something like:

```
Project rootProject = DefaultProject.project(":")
```

The Gradle 6.6.1 API defines Project as an interface, and it's documentation does not mention any static methods. I'm avoiding the `org.gradle.api.internal.project.` package, I want to stick to supported APIs.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a way to omit that parameter skip, and just use something like:

You would basically assign a global static variable to the project reference during the [build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), but there is no guarantees on the state of the `project` instance:

```
public class MyUtil {
    
    private static Project project;
    
    public static void setProject(Project project) {
        MyUtil.project = project;
    }

}
```

> The Gradle 6.6.1 API defines Project as an interface, and it's documentation does not mention any static methods.

The [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) interface is just that, the Gradle project. It is a means to interact with the project.

Having a bunch of static utility methods that does not participate in the Gradle build lifecycle isn't the greatest. Instead, if those utility methods are performing a lot of work or making modifications to a project, then consider migrating that logic to either a [custom Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) and/or [custom Gradle tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html).

By doing that, Gradle will be able to cache and do whatever optimization is can which will lead to improved builds.